# How to link axes of all plots in a Bokeh layout?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, bokeh, axes

I am designing a Bokeh layout using the Bokeh server. I am defining two main columns (see attached image), and I am attempting to link the x-axis of all plots on the right column. The problems are that:

- I am trying to make this app as dynamic as possible, which mean that depending on the case-study, not all the plots will be available, and each individual plot is set from a separate function
- Each plot object is stored in a list, and I don't know how to access their properties
- The reference plot is not known *a priori* so I don't see how I can implement the example in the [Bokeh doc](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html) - in other words, I need to first plot all the subplots to then get the relevant x_range

So I was wondering if it is possible to set the linking behaviour *a posteriori* once all plots in the column are defined (i.e. the output of `plotDataset` below). My intuition is to loop through the objects, get the children and set the `x_range` to the first plot, but I don't know how to do that.

Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve. Ideally, I would get the x_range of the first plot of `fCol` and apply it to all other plots just before `return column(fCol)`

Any idea is greatly appreciated! And also, I am fairly beginner with Python so please shout if you see anything else horrible!

Thank you

```py
def plotTS(data, col):
    tTmp = []

    # A loop that defines each tab of the plot
    for i in range(len(col)):
        fTmp = figure()

        fTmp.circle(data[:]['time'], data[:][col[i]], color=color)

        # Append tab
        tTmp.append(Panel(child=fTmp))

    # Return the tabs
    return Tabs(tabs=tTmp)    

def plotDataset(data):
    col = ['NDVI', 'EVI'] # Name of the tabs

    fCol = []
    fCol.append(plotTS(data, col))

    # NOTE: I use an append approach because in reality plotTS is called more than once

    return column(fCol)

# General layout - I did not include the code for the left column
layout = row(leftColumn, plotDataset(data))
```

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4PlA.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below (Bokeh v1.1.0).

```
from bokeh.models import Panel, Tabs, Column, Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler

def modify_doc(doc):

    leftColumn = Column(figure())

    def plotTS(data, col):
        tTmp = []

        for i in col:
            fTmp = figure()
            fTmp.circle(data['x'], data['y'], color='black')
            tTmp.append(Panel(child=fTmp, title = i))

        return Tabs(tabs=tTmp)    

    def plotDataset(data):
        col = ['NDVI', 'EVI'] 
        fCol = plotTS(data, col)

        shared_range = None
        for panel in fCol.tabs:
            fig = panel.child
            if shared_range is None:
                shared_range = fig.x_range
            else:
                fig.x_range = shared_range

        return Column(fCol)

    layout = Row(leftColumn, plotDataset(data = dict(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [1, 2, 3])))
    doc.add_root(layout)


io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server(applications = {'/app': Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))}, io_loop = io_loop, port = 5002)
server.start()
server.show('/app')
io_loop.start()
```